# make emacs rgrep default to last search term rather than word at point

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs, is there a way to make rgrep default to searching the last term that was passed to it rather than the word at point? I almost always want to do the former rather than the latter. I looked at the help for rgrep, but it was silent on this point.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as off topic. It's about emacs, which is a tool that is used by programmers, and the solution involves writing code (see answer below). I fail to see how this is any different from most other questions I've seen with an emacs tag.

Comment: Emacs developer Juri Linkov referred to my question in [a discussion about defining behavior for regexp-reading commands](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/bug-14405-24-3-50-read-regexp-defaults-function-td286114.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pick through the source code, you find that you can get what you want by setting the variable `find-tag-default-function`.  You could also redefine the function `grep-tag-default`, or associate a property with the major mode via [`put`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Plists.html).  Here's a solution that sets the variable:

```
(setq find-tag-default-function 'last-grep-tag)
(defun last-grep-tag ()
  (if grep-regexp-history
      (car grep-regexp-history)
    ""))
```